# What EXACTLY does mutating a child via emitted event .sync modifier do?

Tags: vue.js

So I've been investigating how mutating child props from the parent can be done.
I already encountered the pitfall with using v-model.
It throws this error:

```
[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "number1"
```

I learnt to deal with this problem by emitting events from the child and using .sync modifier in the parent.

However, I still feel like I didnt really understand whats going on under the hood in both cases.
As far as I understood, when mutating the childs properties from parent with v-model, the mutated data also mutates for any other parent importing the child.

To test this out, I built the following setup:

I have a child component with two inputs:
One using v-model, the other an emitted event to mutate the childs props.
We call it "compA":

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input
    :value="number1"
    @change="$emit('update:number1', $event.target.value)"
    placeholder="number1emittedEvent"
    />
    <input v-model="number1" placeholder="number1vmodel">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default{
  name: "compA",
  props: {
    number1: String
  }
}
</script>
```

compA is being imported by compZ and compB. compZ also imports compB, and then compZ is finally being imported by myComplexView5.vue (my project uses routing).

compB:

```
    <template>
  <div>
    <h1>compB containing compA</h1>
    <compA/>
    <p v-text="number1"></p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import compA from "@/components/complexComponent5/compA.vue"
export default {
  name: "compB",
  components: {
    compA
  },
  data(){
    return {
      number1:''
    }
  }
}

</script>
```

compZ:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <compA :number1.sync="number1"/>
    <br>
    <compB />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import compA from "@/components/complexComponent5/compA.vue"
import compB from "@/components/complexComponent5/compB.vue"

export default {
  name: "compZ",
  components: {
    "compA" : compA,
    "compB" : compB
  },
  data(){
    return {
      number1:''
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

myComplexView5.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>And More testing</h1>
    <compZ />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import compZ from "@/components/complexComponent5/compZ.vue"

export default{
  name: "myComplexView5",
  components: {
    compZ
  }
}
</script>
```

Now, I expected the following behavior:
When inputting into the inputfield which has v-model, I'd expect the paragraph inside  compB to display the changes, since its text value is bound to the number1 prop from child compA. Since I mutated the childs props directly, the changed value should show up in any of the childs parents (or grandparents and so on).

But it doesnt. And it gets even better: When I use the inputfield with the event emitting from child to parent, the paragraph inside compB receives the changes!
This is basically the opposite of what I've learned from the [sync modifier docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier):

> In some cases, we may need “two-way binding” for a prop. Unfortunately, true two-way binding can create maintenance issues, because child components can mutate the parent without the source of that mutation being obvious in both the parent and the child.
>
> That’s why instead, we recommend emitting events in the pattern of update:myPropName. For example, in a hypothetical component with a title prop, we could communicate the intent of assigning a new value with:
>
> `this.$emit('update:title', newTitle)`
>
> Then the parent can listen to that event and update a local data property, if it wants to

Maybe this is caused by the data() inside compB which sets number1 to EMPTYSTRING when the component rerenders? I don't know, I'm very new to vue and I don't really understand when components rerender. I also used this

```
data() {
  return {
    number1: ''
  }
}
```

inside compB To prevent this error from occuring:

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.
```

I don't really know how else to prevent this error from occuring, since it seems that even though compB imported the prop from compA, the prop still needs to be declared in compB Oo

---

EDIT:
I just found out that in the code I'm using, compZ still had this paragraph element:

```
  <p v-text="number1"></p>
```

The string inputted into the inputfield appeared there, NOT in the paragraph element of compB. For some reason, even though I get no errors, neither through the emitted event from compA, nor through the v-model from compA does any change to the props inside compA show any impact inside compB... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put your example code in a snippet at the bottom of the post so that we're on the same page about what code is actually being talked about (I removed the line with the `<p v-text="number1"></p>` from `compB`, because that component doesn't have a prop or data/computed property for `number1`).

Your `compA` component takes in a `number1` prop, which it then uses for two inputs:

- The first input uses the prop as its `value` and then emits an `'update:number1'` event with the input's value in response to the input's `change` event. This allows you to specify the `.sync` modifier when the parent component binds a value to the `compA` component's `number1` prop (as you do in `compZ`).
- The second input directly binds the value of the `number1` prop via `v-model`. This is not recommended (for reasons I'll explain), which is why you are seeing the `"Avoid mutating a prop directly"` warning. The effect of directly binding the `number1` prop to this input is that whenever the value of this second input changes, the value of `number1` will change, thus changing the value of the first input, and finally causing that first input to emit the `update:number1` event. Technically Vue allows you to do this, but you can see how it can get confusing.

Your `compB` component simply renders some texts and a `compA` component without passing a value as a `number1` prop to `compA`.

Your `compZ` component renders a `compA` component, binding its own `number1` property value with the `.sync` modifier to the `compA` component. This `compA` component instance does not share any data with the `compA` component instance in the `compB` component, so we can't expect any changes to either component to affect the other.

```js
Vue.component('compA', {
  template: `
    <div>
      <input
        :value="number1"
        @change="$emit('update:number1', $event.target.value)"
        placeholder="number1emittedEvent"
      />
      <input v-model="number1" placeholder="number1vmodel">
    </div>
  `,
  props: {
    number1: String
  }
})

Vue.component('compB', {
  template: `
    <div>
      <h1>testString</h1>
      <compA />
    </div>
  `
})

Vue.component('compZ', {
  template: `
    <div>
      <compA :number1.sync="number1"/>
      <br>
      <compB />
    </div>
  `,
  data() {
    return {
      number1: ''
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>
    <h1>And More testing</h1>
    <comp-z/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!:)
I updated my question, the Code of compB that I had posted was incomplete. 
While posting my question I discovered some obvious errors myself and corrected them, but in this case I had messed up because I forgot to update my code inside the question...^^

Comment: the paragraph in compB is important, because I want to investigate some of the inner workings of vue with it. When I use v-model on the prop of a child, I manipulate the prop directly, which means that I change the prop inside the child component, is that correct? So when parent components of this child rerender, they all must show the prop of the respective child in its new state, right? If so, then why doesn't the paragraph of compB (with the updated code) update when I update the prop of compA from compZ using v-model?  It doesn't when I use the emitted event, which is as expected, but else

Comment: I'm having a hard time following your questions. Let me try to respond to some misconceptions you might be having: "So when parent components of this child rerender" - a component can only have one parent component. "they all must show the prop of the respective child in its new state, right?"- no, if you directly modify a component's prop value, that value will not propagate up to the parent, and when the parent rerenders, the child component prop's value will be reset to whatever the parent passes in.

Comment: Also, your `compB` component doesn't pass any props to the `compA` in its template, so no data is being shared in that parent-child relationship.

Comment: Thanks! "a component can only have one parent component." really? But in my code example, I could very well import the child from many parents? Lets say I had a paragraph in compA, which I want to show up in compB, C, D and E. Then I just import compA into these components right, and then compA has multiple parents, doesnt it?

Comment: No, in that case you would have two separate instances of `compA` which wouldn't share any data by default. It order for the data in one instance of `compA` to be shared with the other instance of `compA`, you would need to explicitly define how that data would be shared (i.e. how each parent of both instances would pass their data into each component and how the two parent components would share their data between each other).

Comment: Erm, okay but...doesnt this render the whole concept of components futile? The components shall be reusable, so I must be able to implement say, a form component which will appear in several sections of the site, into many parent components which form the respective section of the site. Otherwise I would repeat myself by writing 5 separate forms for 5 separate sections of the site?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201335/discussion-between-thanksd-and-baryon123).